# Adding to a multidimensional associative array (in PHP)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm returning an associative array via PDO that has the structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pesttopicID] => 42
            [sPestName] => CMSM Trap Surveying and Pest Management
            [quizID] => 609
            [bTier1] => 1
            [sDesc] => Workshop assessment
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pesttopicID] => 34
            [sPestName] => Trap Surveyor
            [quizID] => 451
            [bTier1] => 1
            [sDesc] => Competency for CM OAP
        )
)
```

I want to add a key-value pair to the "inner" array, but all my attempts of trying to use posted solutions to the generic issue of adding to an associative array...

```
:
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$newkey='myNewKey';
$newval='myNewValue';
foreach($results as $row){
  $results[][$newkey] = $newval;
  foreach ($row as $key=>$value){
    ... some reporting stuff
    }
}
```

...result in the pair being added to the "outer" array e.g.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array <---- I want the new pair in this "inner" array
        (  
            [pesttopicID] => 42
            [sPestName] => CMSM Trap Surveying and Pest Management
            [quizID] => 609
            [bTier1] => 1
            [sDesc] => Workshop assessment
        )

    [1] => Array  <---- I want the new pair in this "inner" array
        (  
            [pesttopicID] => 34
            [sPestName] => Trap Surveyor
            [quizID] => 451
            [bTier1] => 1
            [sDesc] => Competency for CM OAP
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [myNewKey] => myNewValue
        )
)
```

Is this possible?

Thanks/Tom

Comment: so you want `[myNewKey] => myNewValue` added to each sub-array?

Comment: For your future refrence `$results[][$newkey] = $newval;` the `[]` means create a new element on the end of `$results` and add something to it. That's why you had some issues.

Comment: Read how to access array items using the [square brackets syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***You have to it like below:-***

```
$newkey='myNewKey';
$newval='myNewValue';
foreach($results as &$row){ //use reference variable 
  $row[$newkey] = $newval;// remove the second  foreach if not necessary
  //if second foreach is necessary then add it no problem
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/856983

***Or you can do like this also:-***

```
$newkey='myNewKey';
$newval='myNewValue';
foreach($results as $key=>$row){ //use key now 
  $results[$key][$newkey] = $newval;// remove the second  foreach if not necessary
  //if second foreach is necessary then add it no problem
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/856987

Comment: Thank you. And I've also now learnt about the &$row construct - I'd not encountered that in my previous reading around the topic. Cheers/Tom